# Is ZeroMemory the windows equivalent of null terminating a buffer?

Tags: windows, winapi, initialization, buffer

For example I by convention null terminate a buffer (set buffer equal to zero) the following way, example 1:

```
char buffer[1024] = {0};
```

And with the `windows.h` library we can call `ZeroMemory`, example 2:

```
char buffer[1024];
ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

According to the documentation provided by microsoft: ZeroMemory `Fills a block of memory with zeros.` I want to be accurate in my windows application so I thought what better place to ask than stack overflow.

Are these two examples equivalent in logic?

Comment: Why would you need to call an API function here when the C++ language does all you need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sometimes just [to make it blindingly obvious](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050628-07/?p=35183) ;-)

Comment: In fact, the C++ compiler is likely to convert the first (portable, standard) syntax into the appropriate API call for fast zeroing.

Comment: The sdk often just defines ZeroMemory to use memset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two codes are equivalent.  The entire array is filled with zeros in both cases.

In the case of `char buffer[1024] = {0};`, you are explicitly setting only the first `char` element to `0`, and then the compiler implicitly [*value-initializes*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the remaining 1023 `char` elements to `0` for you.

In C++11 and later, you can omit that first element value:

```cpp
char buffer[1024] = {};
char buffer[1024]{};
```